# Why "im selben" but also "in demselben"?

Tags: word-usage

I am not asking about inflection, but about "dem" being part of "demselben", or so it is suggested by writing it not separated (?), but contracted, "dem" forms prepositon "im".

Is this something exclusive to "derselbe"? Or are there more occurences of an article (?) being "part" of another word but then forming a contraction with the preposition?

And either way, how can it be argued looking at this usage that "dem" does not have to be written separately? Intuitively, seperating it is one of the most common mistakes of Germans. Thinking of "der gleiche" also shows why it could be this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While *im* might look like a contraction, it doesn't behave as one: *im* and *in dem* are not distributionally equivalent.* For some examples, see [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/53102/35111) or Maria Cieschinger, *The Contraction of Preposition and Definite Article in German – Semantic and Pragmatic Constraints*, dissertation, university of Osnabrück, 2016, [link](https://osnadocs.ub.uni-osnabrueck.de/handle/urn:nbn:de:gbv:700-2016041214408).

Therefore, in the following pair, the second variant isn't derived from the first; they both exist independently.

> in demselben Moment
> im selben Moment

As to the spelling of *derselbe* as one word, that's just a quirk; with both parts inflecting independently, *der* and *selbe* stand in precisely the same syntactic relationship as *der* and *gleiche*. The spelling could be in imitation of Latin *idem*.

<sup>* The argument is exactly parallel to that for (apparent) contractions in English: *can't* looks like a contraction of *cannot* but is an independent word. For instance, *can't you see him?* cannot be derived from ungrammatical *cannot you see him?*</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Beside *der-/die-/dasselbe*, there's also *der-/die-/dasjenige*.

Both are demonstrative pronouns as *der/die/das* itself, *dieser/diese/dieses*, *jener/jene/jenes*, *solcher/solche/solches*.

Other tricky demonstrative pronouns are *derlei*, *dergleichen*, *selbst*, and *selber*.

Comment: selbst is a particle. But I thank you for your answer with more similar word.

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/selbst — They think it's a demonstrative pronoun.